# Css drop-down menu transition effect

Tags: css

Nowadays I am building a website and now I am making the menu-bar. Fortunately I have found a nice tutorial on the internet, and so far I have successfully implemented it. The tutorial and the source code can be found here:
[source code of the menubar](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-build-a-kick-butt-css3-mega-drop-down-menu--net-15129)
And the result of this can be found here: [Live Demo site](http://nettuts.s3.amazonaws.com/819_megamenu/demo/index.html)
Actually, I would like to add an transition effect to my dropdown menus. I would like to have the following effect: When I move the mouse to one of the menubar the drop-down menu will show up with a "fade-in" effect changing the opacity(If I am not mistaken, the fade-in effect is connected to change the opacity). And If I would move to another position with the mouse the drop-down goes back slowly, changing the opacity from 1 to 0.

Needless to say, I have already tried different solutions for it, but none of them worked :\ My last attempt was the following but it did not worked properly. I see the effect, but the whole menu bar is screwed up.

```
.dropdown_1column,
.dropdown_2columns,
.dropdown_3columns,
.dropdown_4columns,
.dropdown_5columns {
visibility:visible!important;
opacity:0;
transition:opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition:opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition:opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
-o-transition:opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
...
```

I hope you could help me, I would appreciate it, Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks in advance, I look forward to it ;)

Comment: that's okay, feel free to simplify! But later will it be good with gradient too? :)

Comment: Can we use a bit of jquery? Animating both the top link and the parent together is a bit fuzzy...

Comment: of course! We can use that too! I really appreciate that you are still working on it, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Sorry i cant handle it D: im going to sleep here is 0:47 http://jsfiddle.net/yq2Lm09o/

Comment: ohh i see thanks anyway! So is there no any way to do this, or it is quite complicated to get it done? Have a nice day! I found find a website where it is well explained. The examples (from the 2nd one) with name of "Menu one" represents the effect what i want...

Comment: @Kharchi hey man! I think i have done it with the original html and css files! Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kLfp1o6k/ I have a little problem: first is when I move the mouse under the menubar, the dropdown menus still show up! The second is when I move out from the menu, at the beginning of the hover effect the dropdown windows jumps away with some(cca. 5) pixels. Do you know the solutions of it? If you write the result as an answer, I can accept it, so you got the points, and actually you was the one who has solved the problem ;). Thanks in advance!

Comment: The main problem is why its showing up: because the div is not hidden, its just opacified : 'opacity: 0'

Comment: @Kharchi Ahh okay! I tried it, but if I put "visibility:hidden" before the line of the "opacity:0", the drop down does not show up. Never mind, You have already helped me a lot, thanks a lot for everything! Best wishes! :)

Comment: That is the same problem : 'visibility: hidden' or 'display:none' cant be animated. We can use key-frames css3 to archive similar effect or js. http://jsfiddle.net/kLfp1o6k/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can animate dropdown  with this:

```
$('#menu li').mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).find('[class^="dropdown"]').stop();
        $(this).find('[class^="dropdown"]').css({'overflow':'visible','max-height': '1000px'});
        console.log($(this).children('ul'));
    }).mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).find('[class^="dropdown"]').delay(400).queue(function (next) {
            /*********************************** 0.4s in css ***************/
            $(this).css({'overflow':'hidden','max-height': '0'});
            next();
        });
    });
```

We cant animate the top menu item because it have a gradient: CSS3 gradients cant still be transitioned.

**Here you go**: http://jsfiddle.net/kLfp1o6k/7/

And works a bit better witouth borders: http://jsfiddle.net/kLfp1o6k/8/ --- replaced with box-shadow

Im glad to be able to help you :D

Comment: great! It is getting better and better, I really appreciate your help, thanks! I changed the "delay" to 200, with this, the menu-bar is almost ready :) What is your opinion, why the drop down menu jumps to left-upper-ward with some pixels when we move out with the mouse?

Comment: I am much obliged to you :)

Comment: If you have other question i will be happy to answer :D And sorry for bad english

Comment: Your english is kinda good , no problem with that at all :) I would like to have two question if you don't mind: 1st: Where did you learn the web-programming languages, by own as fun or in school? You are quite good at it ;) 2nd: I have realized that If I move out for example from the "4 Columns" named menu, the links in the drop-down menu get blue and vague. Shall we do something at the "hover state"? I am also sorry for bad expressions and misunderstandings in Css and JS...

Comment: 1) Thanks :) 2) I have learnt all that on internet for free :D (Still learing)  I learnt because of my family business, italian school is kind of old. I love coding :D The links are blue because the style is not defined yet. Blue its browsers default. http://jsfiddle.net/kLfp1o6k/9/

Comment: Niiice! I like the result very much  thanks for everything! I also love coding, but I rather use other languages like python, java, c++.  I have been using these web-programming languages for 1 year, but these are quite interesting too! I wish you the best for the future, and again thanks a lot! ;)

Comment: I will fix soon the other hover problems i must do something else before sorry.

Comment: Later is okay for me. I also have to learn for my exam called Internet-GIS. Have a following nice day! Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70050/discussion-between-mirind4-and-kharchi).

Comment: Please give me an email address(or drop me your address to mine: mokabme@gmail.com ), then I can tell you my opinion about which programming language you should choose, and my view of different languages. It is better than writing here in comment box, and as i see it is not allowed to "spam" it, so :)